# Does a Visual Studio console application use CRT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

Does a Visual Studio console application use CRT?

Is there a way to tell this is true by looking at the linker settings?

Comment: I'm quite sure it uses CRT. See this article: http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2008/02/02/smallest-application-size-for-win32-console-application/ on how to remove it.

Comment: Ok thanks that is the kind of information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a console app will use the CRT.

The CRT is responsible for static data setup and numerous housekeeping functions. If you want to disable CRT you would need to write a lot of boilerplate code. Of course if you don't use basic string manipulation, statics, etc then you can safely remove the CRT lib from your project.

Personally, I wouldn't, but that's just me.